# Mute PHP mysql_* deprecated errors for apache logs

Tags: php, apache, deprecated

Wordpress is still using `mysql_*` functions that are deprecated so Apache's `error.log` file is swelling.

Is it possible somehow to ignore those specific warnings, so none of the `mysql_*` deprecation errors for specific project will be shown ?

For example with some `.htaccess` entry or PHP function.

Comment: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: use PHP5.4 Until Wordpress decide to update their code

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix those errors instead of hiding them. You may face a greater challenge later when the functions are removed.

Comment: @bansi `wordpress` is delivered to the project as a black box, so I cannot modify their files.

Comment: @DarylGill That's not possible because of other projects that requires `5.5`

Comment: looks like you have to live with it for now. watch out for the first chance to escape. good luck. Edit: looks like there is a wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/

Comment: @bansi Look at Alvaro's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tweaking the error reporting level to hide `E_DEPRECATED` stuff is probably not the best option because you'll lose the ability to see that information in your own code. And PHP does not offer enough granularity to filter out deprecated notices by function or library. Your only option, I'm afraid, is to write your own [custom error handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler).

(Disclaimer: I don't know whether WordPress implements a custom error handler as well. If it does, you'll have to be careful in order to not break it.)

It can be tricky if you've never done it before. Among other things, you need to ensure that you're obeying `error_reporting` and the `@` operator and you're aborting when you have to. Whatever, a simplified and not tested starting point could be this:

```
function ignore_mysql_deprecated($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    if( $errno===E_DEPRECATED && preg_match('/^mysql_.+\(\): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future/U', $errstr) ){
        // Ignore
        return true;
    }else{
        // Call standard error handler
        return false;
    }
}
set_error_handler('ignore_mysql_deprecated');
```

If WordPress does not offer a standard mechanism to change the error handler, you can always plug this code in with the [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

**Tested solution**

To mute any `mysql_` calls in your project, we have to create a `mute.php` file:

```
<?php

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
  return strpos($errstr, 'mysql_') === 0;
}, E_DEPRECATED);
```

and add in apache configuration following line:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file mute.php
```

Comment: That's it, Álvaro! Your solution works like a charm, thank you ! Let me edit your answer to provide tested solution.

Comment: FYI: Wordpress doesn't register its own error handler.

Comment: Wow, excellent solution. And thanks, @hsz for adding the tested solution. I'm sure it'd be useful to many other people :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the deprecated warnings, but I don't think you can only avoid the mysql_* ones.

To disable it, use this in your PHP scripts (better if there's only mysql_* related code in this scripts so you don't lose any other deprecated information):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```